# Prevent iphone from sleeping but allow screen lock

Tags: iphone

using iphone SDk3.0, how does one prevent the iphone from sleeping so wifi remains
on but still allow the screen to be dimmed(locked).

Disabling the idle timer is no good as that prevents screen lock and drains the battery really quick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key in your info.plist file. This will tell the system that your application needs the Wifi even if the screen is locked.

Without this key, the wifi will be shut down after some time.

Comment: I already have this key set, it does not prevent iphone sleeping which  turns the wifi off. That key just appears to keep the wifi on when youre app is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you will play an audio file every few seconds, the iPhone will not get to the "deep sleep" state which may solve your issue. For a well explained solution see: [How-to: Prevent iPhone from Deep Sleeping](http://marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/)

If this solution won't work for you, you may read the Apple official documentation regarding the subject: [Apple Documentation: Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

To make a long story short, only simple specific tasks are allowed which are: location, audio and voip. Notice that the voip includes a network session as you needed, but I doubt that if Apple will approve an application which abuse this feature.